# Safari ITP logs users out after 7 days?(firebase phone number auth)

Tags: firebase-authentication, safari

I use firebase to login by phone number on a `Flutter` Web app, but it seems like I get logged out after 7 days.

I'm not sure if this is caused by `ITP` or not. I read that there's a 7day cap on storage like cookies and local storage where the `ID` token is usually stored.

Does `ITP` delete everything in storage?

The Firebase `SDK` should be first party, acting on first party storage. So by that logic, I should not be logged out after 7 days. Unless `ITP` cannot selectively delete stuff from storage, and deletes everything instead.

I've been looking for ways to keep the user logged in after 7 days, but all solutions need some data to be persisted on client side storage.

So far, it doesn't seem possible if `ITP` blindly deletes all.

Would appreciate thorough explanations and guidance, and whether I should give up on trying to keep users logged in past the 7 day mark.